# Angular 2 Get Router Parameters From Past Routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a URL structure set up in my app like this:

`app.com/project/:id/person/:id/task/:id`

I have the routing working properly and I am grabbing the id for the current route/component with:

`this._params.snapshot.params` where _params = ActivatedRoute.

My question is: how can I get the project ID or person ID when on a task. (I need it for the breadcrumb bar.)

Bonus question: I also attempted to grab this with `window.location.pathname` and then manually pull out the IDs. However, I cannot find a life cycle hook that fires after a component/view is rendered. All of the ones I tried fire before the template is rendered or after the component is removed (like navigating away). Is there a life cycle hook for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html) docs. You can use it's properties `parent`/`root`/`pathFromRoot`/etc to traverse the route tree. Somewhere in there should be project id (;

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve parent route param by using this._params.parent.params inside child route subscribe like this:

```
this._params
            .params
            .subscribe(params => {
                this._params.parent.params
                    .subscribe(paramsParent => {
                        // Get parent route param
                        this.id = paramsParent['id'];

                        // Get child route param
                        this.childId = params['id'];
                        this.task = params['task'];
                    });
            });
```